# schema shows through standard client connection but not through ODBC connection?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, schema, odbc, information-schema

Hoping you can help!

## **The Gist**

When I log into an Oracle 11g DB using SQL Developer or DBVisualizer, I can see schemas and execute queries against them.

However, when I use the same credentials to connect via an ODBC connection in Crystal Reports (2008), those schemas do not show up as being available to me.

## **Supporting Information**

- The ODBC connection will ultimately be created on Windows Server 2008
- I'm currently testing the ODBC connection / setup on Win7 Enterprise x64
- We are connecting to the DB via LDAP, not tnsnames (no port information specified -- only the SID and user/pass)
- I can login to the database just fine in DBVisualizer and run a query against it
- The ODBC connection tests successfully after logging in with the username and password
- The connection to ODBC is successfully made by Crystal Reports; it enumerates certain system users, etc. -- just not the users I need access to (and that I have access to via a standard client)
- Our DB is managed separately by a team of DBAs, who aren't the easiest folks to reach. I can, however, get questions answered most likely.

## **Help?**

Any thoughts on where I could start or what the issue might be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected this may have been, it actually appears to be an issue in Crystal Reports 2008 on the client side.

Though I was unable to see the schema enumerated in the list of schemas, after selecting "Update" to link the two, I WAS able to select the various fields necessary and generate the report from the new datasource.

So, end result -- it doesn't show up, but it's there.

Comment: You may use SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES and generate that as report. If you see related tables in this report you are good to go. Design your query in another tool and copy paste it to crystal report.